# How can we target the right most Child of Parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pseudo-class

I have a parent container 'Streams' and it's Childs 'course' i what to set the margin-right: 10px to every child except the child appear at the rightmost of a parent
if I use '.course:nth-child(3n)' it works fine until the browser window is full when we zoom the page or window size change it didn't work properly.

```css
.Streams {
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       padding: 40px 60px 40px 60px;
       display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.course {
      width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Streams">
    <div class="course">
        <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
        <p>
            div 1      
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
        <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
        <p>
            div 2      
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
        <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
        <p>
            div 3      
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
        <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
        <p>
            div 4      
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
        <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
        <p>
            div 4      
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

to Fix this i use but this only effect the very last child.

```
 .course:last-of-type{
     margin-right:0px;
   }
```

Comment: You would need to use media queries for that. So you know if you have 3 on one row or 2 or 4 or .... And target the last one depending on that.

Comment: instead of giving margin to rightmost children , i would suggest you to add `padding-right:10px` to the parent.

Comment: But I need the space of 10px between child elements

Comment: `padding: 40px 50px 40px 60px;` might produce the same visual result.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is take a similar approach that Bootstrap does for its column implementations:

```
.Streams {
       padding: 60px -5px;
       ...
}
.course {
      ...
      margin: 0 5px;
}
```

If the distance between components you want is Xpx then
The formula is horizontal margin (x/2)px on the children, and horizontal padding -(x/2)px on parent.

```css
.Streams {
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       padding: 40px -5px;
       display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.course {
      width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Streams">
    <div class="course">
        <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
        <p>
            div 1      
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
        <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
        <p>
            div 2      
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
        <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
        <p>
            div 3      
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
        <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
        <p>
            div 4      
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
        <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
        <p>
            div 4      
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in (.course:last-child)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.Streams {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 40px 60px 40px 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.Streams .course {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.Streams .course:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Streams">
  <div class="course">
    <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
    <p>
      div 1
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
    <p>
      div 2
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
    <p>
      div 3
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
    <p>
      div 4
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img src="#" alt="BCA" />
    <p>
      div 4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```